# 'Not equal' angular filter ng-options

Tags: angularjs

So I have this select in a view with ng-options. I also have a variable called *CourseID*. I am trying to show the courses which *CourseID* is different from the *CourseID* in the previously mentioned variable.

Here is my code

JS

```
$scope._data.courses = [
  {
    "FullName": "Math",
    "CourseID": 1
  },
  {
    "FullName": "History",
    "CourseID": 2
  },
  {
    "FullName": "PE",
    "CourseID": 3
  },
  {
    "FullName": "Literature",
    "CourseID": 4
  }
]

$scope.data.trainees = [
    {
        "FullName": "Jame Pierre",
        "ID": 54
    },
    {
        "FullName": "Marie Cullan",
        "ID": 78
    },
    {
        "FullName": "Joseph Matthews",
        "ID": 33
    },
    {
        "FullName": "Jean Paul",
        "ID": 15
    }
]

$scope._data.CurrentCourseID = 2;
```

View

```
<tr ng-repeat="trainee in _data.trainees">
    <td>{{trainee.ID}}</td>
    <td>{{trainee.FullName}}</td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" ng-options="course.CourseID as course.Name for course in _data.courses | filter:{ CourseID : '!' + _data.CurrentCourseID }:true" ng-model="CID" ng-change="moveTo(trainee, CID)">
            <option style="display:none" value="">Move to</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td ng-init="$last && refreshPickers()">
        <div style="float: right;">
            <a class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="remove(trainee)">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And it's still not working as expected. The first way shows no courses and the second way shows all the courses.

Comment: None should display anything since they don't have ng-model. Once it has, the second one works fine: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/o7t8JOrSz2TbXtXq?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1. So if you wat help, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, as I did.

Comment: @JBNizet I actually have an ng-model and it still doesn't work